How to deal with Categoricals for scaling
I have a MLP classifier, whose usage is to solve a binary classification problem (say category A vs B). My goal is minimize log loss, however one sanity check I am running is ensuring that probabilities of predicting opposite feature sets, belonging to either A or B, are mutually exclusive and add to 1.
One issue I am running into, is when I use categorical features within my predictions - the probabilities of each event (either belonging to A or B) no longer sum to 1. How can I deal with this issue?
E.G Assume my row of features are [height, weight, order, Red?, Sweet?] and my target values are either 0 which stands for cherry, or 1 which stands for orange.
Then predicting using row [-1,1,3,True,False] versus [1,-1,-3,True,False] would leave me with probabilites that do not sum to 1. My hypothesis is that  the boolean categoricals are not negatives of each other, which is why the probabilities of predicting Cherry and not Cherry(in the second feature set) do not sum to 1.
Note that I am only using scaling on my numeric features, and leaving my categorical values as as one-hot encoded boolean values during the training and testing processes. In addition, I am using Robust Scaler as my dataset has a large amount of outliers.
EDIT: After further thought, I realize the error is most likely due to the boolean features being imbalanced as they can belong to both classes with P() != .50
